# let $T:V\to V$ be a linear map and $(T-aI)^n=0$. Prove $a\neq $b or $\dim V = 0$ $\implies T-bI$ invertible

Tags: linear-algebra

let $T:V\to V$ be a linear map and $(T-a)^n=0$.  Prove $a\neq $b or $\dim V = 0$ $\implies T-b$ invertible.

I'm looking for a proof not involving eigenvalues, as I am able to do this.  I was also given the fact that using $S=\frac{T-a}{b-a}$ might be helpful to consider.

Comment: You haven't defined $W$.

Comment: Yea sorry about that, I fixed it.

Comment: Also, where do $a$ and $b$ come from? Do you mean $T-aI$?

Comment: $a$ and $b$ are scalars of the field of the vector space $V$ and yes: $T-a$ = $T-aI$ is what I meant

Comment: Is $n$ suppose to be the dimension of $V$?

Comment: No $n$ is some natural number such that $(T-aI)^n=0$

Comment: $0=(T-a)^n=((T-b)+(b-a))^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(b-a)^k(T-b)^{n-k}$. Therefore, $1=(T-b)[-(b-a)^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}(b-a)^k(T-b)^{n-k-1}]$. This means that $T-b$ has an inverse.

Comment: Wow that's amazing thank you!

Comment: @conditionalMethod Seems like this should be an answer, not just a comment.